# How can we read hive transactional tables and perform delete operations on it through SparkSql

Tags: hive, transactions, apache-spark-sql

How can we read hive transactional tables and perform delete operations on it using SparkSql.

Comment: I think hive is not suitable for transactional table.

Comment: Post 0.14, new API’s have been added to comply with ACID properties while performing transactions @DennisLi

Answer (score 0):

In this moment there is an [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348) on this topic. 
Spark does not support any feature of hive's transaction tables.

Comment: I read somewhere that this can be achieved through LLAP but didnt comppletely understand it.

Comment: can you post the source?